# Underlying rows in Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a certain number of columns and a primary key column (suppose OriginalKey). I perform a GROUP BY on a certain sub-set of those columns and store them in a temporary table with primary key (suppose GroupKey). At a later stage, I may need to get more details about one or more of those groupings (which can be found in the temporary table) i.e. I need to know which were the rows from the original table that formed that group. Simply put, I need to know the mappings between GroupKey and OriginalKey.  What's the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Example:

```
Table Student(
StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Level INT, --Grade/Class/Level depending on which country you are from)
HomeTown TEXT,
Gender CHAR)

INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT HomeTown, Gender, COUNT(*) AS NumStudents FROM Student GROUP BY HomeTown, Gender
```

On a later date, I would like to find out details about all towns that have more than 50 male students and know details of every one of them.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to store the fields you grouped on in your temporary table, so you can join back to the original table. e.g. if you grouped on fieldA, fieldB, and fieldC, you'd need something like:

```
select original.id
from original
inner join temptable on
   temptable.fieldA = original.fieldA and
   temptable.fieldB = original.fieldB and
   temptable.fieldC = original.fieldC
```

Comment: You'd probably need fields A, B and C in the result set too, at least in the general case.

Comment: Turns out this was all I needed. My challenge was that my GROUP BY string is dynamically generated meaning that my TempTable had to have all columns to accommodate all possible combinations of GROUP BY. All I had to do was to generate the JOIN clause dynamically using Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

How about joining the 2 tables using the GroupKey, which, you say, are the same?

Or how about doing:

```
select * from OriginalTable where 
GroupKey in (select GroupKey from my_temp_table)
```